# How can I disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in apache xampp?

Tags: apache, xampp, tls1.2

Does anyone know how I can disable tls 1.0 and tls1.1?

I'm getting the following error when I scan the site using https://www.ssllabs.com.

`This server supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. Grade capped to B`

How can I disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on the server running apache.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this line in httpd-ssl.conf file.

`SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1`

Comment: Another way to do that: SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 or SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3 (Apache 2.4.37 or greater )